# How do I fix this NameError?

Tags: ruby, scope, metaprogramming

I want to use the value `v` inside of an instance method on the metaclass of a particular object:

```
v = ParserMap[kind][:validation]   # We want to use this value later.
s = ParserMap[kind][:specs]
const_set(name, lambda {
  p = Parser.new(&s)

  # This line starts a new scope...
  class << p
    define_method :validate do |opts|
      v.call(self, opts)  # => NameError! The `class` keyword above
                          #    has started a new scope and we lost
                          #    old `v`.
    end
  end
  p
})
```

Unfortunately, the `class` keyword starts a new scope, so I lose the old scope and I get a NameError. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `class << p` with `class << p; self end.class_eval do` and it will work.

`class << p; self end` will return the metaclass of p, so you can call `class_eval` on it. The block given to `class_eval` will then execute in the context of the metaclass (same as it did before), but without starting a new scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your first inclination might be to use `class_eval` on `p`, like this:

```
p.class_eval {
  ...
}
```

Alas, that won't work, because `class_eval` is a method defined on `Module`, not on `Object`. Since `p` is an instance of an object, not of a `Module` or `Class`, it doesn't have a `class_eval` method.

The trick is to get `p`'s singleton class first, and then run `class_eval` on that. Since that *is* a `Class` (and by extension, a `Module`), it has a `class_eval` method. If you're in 1.9.2 or later, there's a `singleton_class` method you can use:

```
p.singleton_class.class_eval {
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, you can just get the singleton class directly:

```
(class << p; self; end).class_eval {
  ...
}
```

---

As Jorg points out, you can also use `define_singleton_method`:

```
p.define_singleton_method :validate { |opts|
  v.call(self, opts)
}
```

But note that if you do this, the resulting `validate` method will be `private`, which may not be what you want.

Comment: If you're on 1.9.2, you could just use `define_singleton_method` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, here's how it would look like in Ruby 1.9.2:

```
v = ParserMap[kind][:validation]
s = ParserMap[kind][:specs]
const_set(name, ->{
  Parser.new(&s).tap {|p|
    p.define_singleton_method :validate do |opts| v.(self, opts) end
  }
})
```

- replace the explicit return of `p` at the end with the K combinator (`Object#tap`) introduced in Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.0
- replace the `lambda` method call with a proc literal introduced in Ruby 1.9.0
- replace `obj.call(args)` with `obj.(args)` introduced in Ruby 1.9.0
- most importantly: use `Object#define_singleton_method` introduced (or more precisely: going to be introduced) in Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Note: #define_singleton_method makes `validate` private, so this isn't exactly equivalent.